# Bash: kill process in function of the memory used

Tags: bash, shell-script

I made this script to close a process, but I can't compare the `awk` result (`var1`) with an Integer: `var1 -gt 5000`.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1= free -m |awk 'NR == 2'| awk '{print $3}'
var2= ps aux | grep '/opt/skype/skype' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'

while true;
do
     if [ $var1 -gt 5000 ]; then
         echo "La memoria se ha excedido cerrando porcesos"
         kill -9 $var2
     break
     else
     echo "La memoria aun es estable $var1"
     fi
done
```

Could it be a casting problem in bash?

Comment: maybe this will help, https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom not specific to certain app, but it will app with largest memory usage

Comment: You might was to check if the process is still alive after killing it before running again (`kill -0`). Although in almost all instances `kill -9` will end a process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast variables in bash and ksh (use `declare -i var` or `typeset -i var` for interger), but I don't think that is your problem.

The following will set `var1` to nothing while then running the command as normal.

```
var1= free -m |awk 'NR == 2'| awk '{print $3}'
```

If you want the output of free and awk to be set to var1 then the above should read:

```
var1=$( free -m |awk 'NR == 2'| awk '{print $3}' )
```

Comment: @Dark: actually, `var1= cmd1 | cmd1` will put `var1` in the environment for `cmd1`.  It won't even set `var1` at all in the shell.  (There's rarely a difference between an unset variable and one set to the empty string, but it won't show up when you run `set` to dump all variable and function definitions.)

Comment: Also, @ymk369: Instead of using `var2` to find the pid of skype, you should use `pkill -9 skype`.

Comment: thanks @PeterCordes, or I can also use var1 = $ (pidof skype),  but the point was to assign a variable AWK

Answer (score 1):

thanks DarkHeart, my script works.

Here is the resulting code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do   

    var1=$( free -m |awk 'NR == 2'| awk '{print $3}' )
    var2=$( ps aux | grep '/opt/skype/skype' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' )

    if [ $var1 -gt 5460 ]; then
         echo "La memoria se ha excedido cerrando porcesos"
         kill -9 $var2
         break
    else
         echo "La memoria aun es estable $var1"
    fi

    sleep 1

done
```

Comment: I'd sleep longer than that.  Like maybe `sleep 10`.  `while sleep 1m; do` ... works, if you don't care about the loop running the first iteration right away.  Also, use `pkill -9 skype` instead of grepping `ps` output into `var2` (which you could have put inside the if so it only ran when needed.)  Also, use `awk NR==2 {print $3}`, rather than two awk invocations.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok, `awk NR==2 {print $3}`  I did not know, thanks.